# How to aggregate rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe shown in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la4yu.png). It is a sample of pubs in London,UK (3337 pubs/rows). And the geometry is at an LSOA level. In some LSOAs, there is more than 1 pub. I want my dataframe to summarise the number of pubs in every LSOA. I already have the information by using

```
  psdf['lsoa11nm'].value_counts()
```

prints out:

```
City of London 001F    103
City of London 001G     40
Westminster 013B        36
Westminster 018A        36
Westminster 013E        30
                  ... 
Lambeth 005A             1
Croydon 043C             1
Hackney 002E             1
Merton 022D              1
Bexley 008B              1
Name: lsoa11nm, Length: 1630, dtype: int64
```

I cant use this as a new dataframe because it is a key and one column as opposed two columns where one would be lsoa11nm and the other pub count.

Does anyone know how to groupby the dataframe so that there will be only one row for every lsoa, that says how many pubs are in it?

Comment: I apologize that  I don't quite understand... but does `psdf['lsoa11nm'].value_counts().reset_index()` work?

Comment: Legend!!! It worked! Thank you so much!